# spatialite sql and possibly using case

Tags: spatialite

i have a database that has got tables with images and some of the tiles for the images is repeated and i want to eliminate the duplicates based on which imagery is oldest so as to remain with the newest images, i have run the following to get the duplicates from the database but do not know how to delete the row based on the age of the imagery

```
select "index",path from ngi_catalog_aug2012 where "index" in 
(SELECT "index"
 FROM ngi_catalog_aug2012
GROUP BY "index"
HAVING ( COUNT("index") > 1 )
) order by "index"
```

this gives results like

```
index       path

2228BD_23    /data/ngi_old/images_30k_sid/2228/2228BD_23_498_469_12_0007_PAN_RECT.sid

2228BD_23   /data/ngi_old/images_30k_sid/2228BD/2228BD_23_498_469_11_0100_PAN_RECT.sid
```

and i would like to delete for instance the second row

Comment: Does your ngi_catalog_aug2012 table have a primary key? If not then you'll have to delete by the path: DELETE FROM ngi_catalog_aug2012 WHERE path='2228BD/2228BD_23_498_469_11_0100_PAN_RECT.sid';